Estimate bits per pixel from RAW photo
Nowadays many consumer products like smartphones or action cameras support RAW photos. Typically, they spit out a DNG/TIFF file with 16 bit values. However, the actual bit depth of the A/D is rather in the range of 10-14 bit.
I would like to know for a camera what the bit depth of the sensor is, however cannot find a datasheet that explicitly states that information. My question is thus, if it is possible to estimate that information from a given raw image?
An easy check, I found in the internet, presumably is to capture a photo that contains a fully saturated area, for example, by taking a picture of the sun. Then, open the RAW file, for example, in python and note the maximum value. It could be for example 0x3ff (10bit), 0xfff (12bit), or 0x3fff (14bit).
But I guess that this is only half the truth. Because, the values could be scaled/offsetted in any arbitrary way, and thus only looking like 14bit. For example, the maximum value I gathered from my phone's RAW photo was 0x3ff0 - which would indicate something close to 14bit.
Is there any way to recover this information from the RAW file alone?


I would like to know for a camera what the bit depth of the sensor is, however cannot find a datasheet that explicitly states that information. My question is thus, if it is possible to estimate that information from a given raw image?

Sure, take a photo that you presume has nice dynamic range (say, a forest picture in the summer: bright spots and deep shadows, lots of greens, but also some reddish browns), simply count the different values that actually occur in each color channel.
Truth is, though, that I wouldn't be surprised if even in RAW formats you don't get raw sensor data – there's simply a lot of distortion with lenses the size of a smartphone camera lens, so chances are that you always get an image that's already been processed at a bit depth higher than the ADC bit depths, just to make it useful at all, especially in higher-end camera phones. The fact that my camera app lets me choose different resolutions for a RAW image is a very strong indicative of that.
The other thing I could think of is actually measuring quantization noise. Not a trivial task; you'd need to first measure nonlinearity to get the crest factor out, then measure the remaining noise power in narrow bandwidths around the fundamental and harmonics of a sinusoidal power (in a nonlinearity-compensated image); finally, subtract the uncorrelated ("white") noise power you see elsewhere (and hope very strongly that the optical shot and electronic thermal noise are sufficiently white for that).
Not an optical-physical camera characterization person, if I had to devise a prototypical calibration for that:

get camera on tripod, very uniform lighting of known whiteness, and optical intensity meter ready
produce a test board with at least three patches of grey from a black&white laser printer on very white paper – which you calibrate under controlled uniform lighting conditions, so you know, for example, "second patch has twice as much reflectivity as first, third one 8 times as much".
compare "calibration intensity" ratios to "pixel intensity from file you printed" ratios; you get the coefficients for a quadratic equation that models the "intensity in $x$ – printed intensity out $P_{\text{printer}}(x)$" function with three patches (and larger polynomials with more patches).
verify your model by printing other grey patches and showing your equation works
take in-focus photo in same lighting conditions of three+ patches. Look at each color channel individually
average brightness in photographed patches' center areas (to eliminate any border effects) to get empiric intensities
same method as for printer calibration: Find a "patch brightness – photo pixel brightness" function $P_{\text{camera}}(x)$. Note that positively-additive noise (optical shot noise) ends up being consumed by the coefficient to $x^0$ of these polynomials. More patches give more coefficients, but you need a minimum patch size for low-noise averaging, and you want to stick to the center of the picture, where the lens effects are probably the least malevolent.
Using your model from 2.&3., print a $A\cdot\frac{1}{2}(\cos(t)+1)+C,\quad A, C \text{ const.}\in [0,1]$ gradient, 23.35° through your page, corrected for printer nonlinearities. (any angle that guarantees we're hitting sensor pixels independently enough; so anything but perfect 90°, 45° and maybe 30° should be OK)
Take photo, correct nonlinearities of camera. Cut out middle 10%, throw away rest.
A row of the result of 8 should theoretically only contain a single harmonic function (and a constant offset), plus white noise. The difference to that assumption should, given we've done our calibration very diligently, and there's no other sources for correlated noise, be quantization noise.
use a parametric estimator to get the exact frequency of the fundamental
estimate white noise power from a spectrogram, in a region that doesn't contain the fundamental and the first harmonic, at least (in short: not containing any obvious peaks)
estimate energy in a narrow bandwidth around the first harmonic, subtract: that'd be your quantization noise, plus white noise
repeat 8. – 11. for other rows. Since geometric distortion might also cause noise influence things, and you won't see that, make a histogram of observed quantization noise powers, and pick a value from the least end, that doesn't look like "pure luck".
average white noise power estimate for all rows, subtract from estimated quantization+white noise power
Apply known formula for quantization noise power of harmonic signals to estimate bit depth.

To be completely honest, physical uncertainties dominate this problem – how well will you be able to uniformly light the scene? How repeatable are photos? How much lens distortion? Does temperature play a role? Therefore, my conclusion here is that this would be something you could do while you design a camera sensor, to help characterize the ADCs you're using. However, in this setting, since all other effects dominate so much I wonder what use knowing the "actual" bit depth of the ADC is going to be – the ENOB is obviously much smaller.

Thanks for the elaborate answer. I think the procedure you are describing is a good idea but unfortunately out of scope for me.

You could make a histogram of raw codes. If 14 bit adc readings are padded to 16 bits, one would expect the histogram to have a comb-like structure even after scaling/shifting - as long as the applied function is deterministic and applied per-pixel.
The question of «how much accuracy does my sensor have» should include noise (and in some cases lossy compression of raw). For that I would consult one of the online databases specializing in just that.
Have a look at:
https://www.photonstophotos.net/
https://www.strollswithmydog.com/

I have looked at the DNG file and at least they use lossless jpg compression. However, it is still hard to find out any specs about these sensors. The only thing I found out was that GoPro specifies a 12bit fileformat and the histogram also looks like one.

The dcraw library or some of its recent reincarnations allows you to read of raw uncompressed sensel values from a raw file
